# Wagtail customization of admin template for Page Type Model

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

For example i have model like this and i want to add some button or image to the edit template of this page(Admin interface).I did not find a way how to do this using hooks.I think there must be some solution, otherwise it turns out that the pages(Admin interface of Page type model's) cannot be customized. If you have any solution or suggestions,I will be very grateful

```
class SomePage(Page):
    max_count = 1
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text')
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("text"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom `Panel`.

Create a class that inherits `wagtail.admin.panels.Panel`, add any parameters you might want to the init then render whatever you want in `Panel.BoundPanel.render_html()`. You can load any extra needed js/css via `insert_global_admin_js`/`insert_global_admin_css` hooks. You need to pass any additional arguments into `clone()`, these values are accessible in the `BoundPanel` with `self.panel.some_arg`.

Something like:

```
class SomePanel(Panel):
    def __init__(self, something, *args, **kwargs):
        self.something = something
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clone(self):
        return self.__class__(
            something =self.something,
        )

    class BoundPanel(Panel.BoundPanel):
        def render_html(self, parent_context):
            return mark_safe(get_some_html(thing=self.panel.something))
```

Then in your page/model:

```
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    ....
    SomePanel(something='some_value')
]
```

With this route, you're free to display whatever you want on the editor's interface. Could be a live feed to provide dynamic information, or a button to calculate a field on the page for example. Re-usable as well since you can put it into any model, not just the current.

I have an example for customising `FieldPanel`s on my site: https://enzedonline.com/en/tech-blog/import-text-file-into-a-textarea-html-form-field/

The process for `Panel`s is more or less the same for as for `FieldPanel`s, only you don't have a field you're binding to and don't need to call the `super.render_html()` since you're starting from scratch with a Panel. Also, from my understanding, for custom arguments, you use `clone` with `Panel` and `clone_kwargs` with `FieldPanel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Richard Allen.I wanted to do something exactly in the template and not by creating your own panels. But it seems to be the only solution(: 
Thanks anyway for the detailed solution and examples

Comment: There are also components that might be useful for you? https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/template_components.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an image, you can probably use the [HelpPanel](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#helppanel). If the image is known at class definition time, the image info can be in the HelpPanel definition. If it is different per page load, then you will need to [make a custom form class for your page](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/extending/forms.html#using-forms-in-admin-views) and alter the help panel in the form `__init__` method.

The "some button" part of this implies attached behavior so you will probably need to build your own panel type by [extending Panel and BoundPane](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/panel_api.html#wagtail.admin.panels.Panel)l

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cnk, but unfortunately this is not what I want. I just need the same functionality as in [modeladmin](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html).
`Helpanel` is not very flexible, and creating custom panel types just to customize the admin is not a good solution for me (

Comment: What aspect of modeladmin does what you want? It's possible there is an analogous option for pages if you provide more specifics.